# spline : difference between smooth.spline() & bSpline()?

Tags: r, spline, smoothing, bspline

Can someone explain me three questions related to smooth.spline().

1°) Why the knots created within smooth.spline are no evenly spread?

2°) What type of spline is used by smooth.spline ?
When I compare a smooth.spline with no constraint (spar=0) and compare it with a linear model using a B-spline (bSpline function) I have very close curves but identical and the parameters differs.

3°) How can I retrieve the spline matrix from smooth.spline as the one I have from bSpline?

--- Data come from bSpline help: artificial example ---

```
y18 <- c(1:3, 5, 4, 7:3, 2*(2:5), rep(10, 4))
data <- data.frame(y18, x=seq(0,1,length=18))
xx <- seq(0, 1, len = 201)
s2 <- smooth.spline(y=data$y18, x=data$x, nknots = 9, spar=0 )
p  <- predict(s2, xx)

bsx  <- data.frame(bSpline(x=data$x   , knots=s2$fit$knot[5:11], 
degree=3, intercept = FALSE)) 
data <- data.frame(data, bsx)

bs100 <- data.frame(bSpline(x=0:100/100, knots=s2$fit$knot[5:11], 
degree=3, intercept = FALSE)) 
bs100 <- data.frame(x=0:100/100, bs100)

lm_y18 <- lm(data=data[,-2], y18 ~ .)
bs100$y <- predict(lm_y18, bs100)
```

---- question 1 ----

```
s2$fit$knot                # I was expecting to have: 1:7/8
diff(s2$fit$knot)
```

---- question 2 ----

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data=data, aes(x=x, y=y18)) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=p$x, y=p$y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=p02$x, y=p02$y)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=bs100$x, y=bs100$y), color=2) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=s2$fit$knot, lty=2, color="grey")
cbind(s2$fit$coef,lm_y18$coefficients, s2$fit$coef-lm_y18$coefficients)
```

Comment: What is `p02`? It's no where in your code except the `ggplot` function

Comment: You are right I forgot to remove this line from my example. p02 is not needed.